# OpenID or Auth in Django?

Tags: python, django

What are the pros and cons of using [open id](http://openidenabled.com/python-openid/) vs [auth](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)?  Shoud I do both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends whether you want to support Open ID. As to the reasons behind Open ID, in my view the most compelling one is that it avoids requiring your users to have an account just for your site, with all the hassle that involves (yet another username and password to remember).

If you decide you want to use Open ID, there's not need to choose between that and auth - use [`django-openid-auth`](http://code.google.com/p/django-openid-auth/), which adds Open ID support to the auth framework.

Definitely try and avoid using an Open ID implementation that doesn't plug into Django's auth framework - you'll lose a lot of the baked-in goodness of Django (model-level permissions etc).

Comment: my main concern is migrating openid accounts?  Do ppl change the open id provider often?

Comment: Well - on an extensive survey of errr me, I've changed my Open ID provider once (technorati -> Google).

Comment: Do non-tech ppl use openid at all?

Comment: @Timmy, yes. Google accounts use OpenID. Although most non-technical people probably don't consciously choose an OpenID provider.

Comment: thanks.. what about the FB oauth things?  should i consider those?

Answer (score 2):

OpenID and OAuth do different things.  OpenID lets users log into your site.  OAuth lets people give your site access to their data elsewhere.  On the other side of the coin, OAuth gives you a secure way to let users access their data in your service  from elsewhere.

If you implement OpenID, don't implement an OpenID producer.  Everyone's already got an OpenID, whether they know it or not.  Just consume openids from elsewhere.  Migrating OpenIDs shouldn't be hard.  Just make sure that a user account can connect via multiple OIDs, then they can add new ones as needed, and remove when they're done with them.

**Edit:**  Just saw that you were talking about django auth, not oauth.  Oops.  The second paragraph still stands.